# Wordpress multisite subdomain showing server blank page [SOLVED]

Tags: wordpress, multisite

After a wordpress multisite setup, any new crated site(subdomain) inthe network is not mapping to wordpress, otherwise the subdomain show server blank page instead of wordpress site.

What can be wrong?

I have set up multisite in a wordpress by the following steps:

1) added `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );` in to `config.php`

2) have set up network configuration in wordpress wp admin

3) added

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

in

`config.php`

3) added

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

in

`.htaccess`

4) setup DNS A record `*` `WEBSITE_IP_ADDRESS`

> UPDATE:
>
> I found the solution, need to add `ServerAlias *.mydomain.com` in the
>   `httpd.conf` of the appropriate domain.

Comment: Small thing, but I'm assuming ".haccess" was a typo? It should be ".htaccess"

Comment: @GregBurkett *htaccess, edited now

Comment: Cool! You didn't mention it specifically in your post, but have you gone through the mapping steps in Network Admin here: /wp-admin/network/sites.php

Comment: @GregBurkett yes, I forgot to mention this.